# validar que se guarda información en mysql con php y bootstrap

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, bootstrap

hola a todos tengo una consulta, como dice el titulo, alguien conoce la forma de validar que el proceso de guardar los datos en la bd se a hecho correcto o incorrecto con bootstrap y php, actual mete lo tengo con puro PHP pero al usuario lo manda a otra pagina y lo que quiero es que dentro de la misma pagina se verifique esto sin estar cambiando de pagina.

Comment: creo que le falta informacion a este post , incluso te lo podrian borrar. Por otra parte yo te digo que podrias usar ajax para guardar información en mysql , a y bootstra es un framework de estilos no para procesos. Podrias usar `toastr` para cuando se ejecute bien el preoceso de ajax

Comment: @antonio sanchez Podrias agregar el codigo del formulario para ayudarte

Comment: tendras que hacerlo con ajax, si quieres validar ese proceso sin salir de la misma página, sino antes de redireccionar con php verificas que se salvaron los datos y si no fue satisfactorio puedes pasar x variables y renderizar el error